# can a field be embedded into product of hyperbolas as a closed subset?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let's say we have a algebraically closed field $k$. Let $H=\{(x_1,x_2)\in k^2 : x_1x_2=1\}$ be an affine variety. My question is, can $k^1$ be embedded into $H \times H$ as a closed subset?

My idea to approach this problem would be to look at the rings of regular functions on $\mathbb k^1$ (which is $k [x]$) and of $H \times H$ (which is a tensor product $k[H] \otimes k[H]$), because if such an embedding would exist, it would induce an epimorphism of $k$-algebras $k[H] \otimes k[H] \rightarrow k[x]$.

So let's find the ring $k[H]$. From what I understand, we can find it by restrictions of elements from the ring $k[x_1,x_2]$ to $H$, so we get $k[H]=k[x_1,x_2]/I(H)$ where $I(H)$ is an ideal consisting of polynomials vanishing on $H$, which in this case is an ideal generated by $g(x_1,x_2)=x_1\cdot x_2$. If I understand correctly, what we get here is $k[H]=\{f\in k[x_1,x_2] : f=a_n x_1^n +...+a_1 x_1 + b_m x_2^m+...+b_1 x_2 + c$ for $a_i,b_j,c\in k\}$. So we take a tensor product of this algebra with itself and i'm stuck here - i don't see what kind of object do we get, nor how to construct an epimorphism onto $k[x]$, and even if I constructed such epimorphism, I wouldn't know how to get a morphism of varieties from the homomorphism of rings of regular functions.

My intuitions is that such and embedding does not exist, because it would have to be a function $f:k^1 \rightarrow k^4$, $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),f_4(x))$, where $f_i$ are polynomials of one variable satisfying $f_1\cdot f_2=f_3\cdot f_4=1$, and i'm having a hard time coming up with nontrivial polynomials of this form.

Comment: Shouldn't you be quotienting out by $g(x_1, x_2) = x_1x_2 - 1$? In the end, one should find $k[H] \simeq k[t,t^{-1}]$.

Comment: Of course, that's a stupid mistake, thank you for correcting me. So the problem right now is a problem in the category of $k$-algebras - is there an epimorphism from $k[t,t^{-1}]\otimes k[t,t^{-1}]$ onto $k[x]$? My intuition tells me there isn't, but i'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tensor product in the comment is just $k[u,v,u^{-1},v^{-1}]$. Any morphism from this to $k[x]$ will have to take $u,v$ to units in $k[x]$, but this has only constants as units. So, the map can not be onto.